# how to write <script> tag on javascript or jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is the code i want to put in

```
var htm = "<center><div id="evp-8847b53dee625a133cfb02e88fd7bbf8-wrap" class="evp-video-wrap"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://convernet.evplayer.com/framework.php?div_id=evp-8847b53dee625a133cfb02e88fd7bbf8&id=Q29udmVybmV0L25ldyBjb252ZXJuZXQvVGhlIGZ1dHVyZS5tcDQ%3D&v=1333642408&profile=default"></script><script type="text/javascript"><!--
_evpInit('Q29udmVybmV0L25ldyBjb252ZXJuZXQvVGhlIGZ1dHVyZS5tcDQ=[evp-8847b53dee625a133cfb02e88fd7bbf8]');//--></script></center>"

$('#inner_slide .module').replaceWith(htm);
```

but its remove the script. please help

Comment: you need to escape your double quotes mate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to escape the double-quote in the string; for example:

```
var myStr = "hi this is an \"inner quote\".";
```

Secondly, break up the string as such:

```
myStr += "some html: <scr"+"ipt>my script</s"+"cript>";
document.write(myStr);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery messes with script tags when you pass HTML to it.

You can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ to pull in the script or use the native javascript option http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS

InnerHTML is also an option.  You can check out this question [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)